# Json Hijacking Restsharp. modify response content before deserialization.

Tags: c#, rest, security, restsharp

Ok. So I'm trying to use Restsharp as a Http Client.

Basicaly I need to modify a response content before deserialization.

Is there a point of extension where I could do this?

You know what I mean?

Form API I, get valid json answer but with `")]}',"`( hijacking prevention) as a prefix.

Now I need to remove it. 
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weel I think I figure it out.

I have to execute result first and then Deserializer class that i have derived from JsonDeserializer;

```
var reult = client.Execute(request);
            var u  = new MyDeserializer().Deserialize<UserGuamInformations>(reult);
```

and part of the class:

```
   public new  T Deserialize<T>(IRestResponse response){
        string str = response.Content;
        response.Content = str.Remove(0, 6);//remove )]}',\n
        return base.Deserialize<T>(response);
    }
```